# Cannot resolve dependencies in sample Google VR Project

Tags: java, android, google-vr

I cloned the project from here `git clone https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk.git`

I imported the `gvr-android-sdk` project into Android Studio:

Opening the `buid.gradle` for the `samples-sdk-treasurehunt` project I see the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-audio:1.60.1'
    compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.60.1'
}
```

See image here:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the recently create issue at https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/431 where I've added an initial solution (change ALL dependency references to 1.60.1 to 1.60.0, not just for the sample you're building.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at https://bintray.com/google/googlevr/sdk-audio

It shows that version 1.60.1 hasn't been pushed to the repository yet. Try setting the versions to 1.60.0 (the latest pushed version)

edit: you may have imported the wrong folder, you need to import the folder that you cloned the repository to (as you need to project-level build.gradle), instead of import `gvr-treasurehunt` import `gvr-android-sdk`

Comment: I wish I could tell you that worked, but it doesn't... Same issue.

Comment: Thanks. The folder I imported was the top-level ``gvr-android-sdk/samples`` directory. In Android Studio it shows a list of 5 projects in the Project pane on the left-hand side of the screen. Do I need to import the specific project, i.e. ``samples-sdk-treasurehunt`` instead?

Comment: You need to import `gvr-android-sdk` not `gvr-android-sdk/samples`

Comment: I did that as well. No cigar.

Comment: Did you select the `samples-sdk-treasurehunt` target ?

Comment: Yes I did. Gradle fails to compile.